# I cant compile code from VS code to run on browser?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03MZQ.png)

Cant run code using VS code why is that? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have react installed and so you don't have package.json file,
I would suggest you to search for create-react-app on google and follow their guide to creating a default react application. (From your image I understand you are trying to learn react)
Steps to follow;

- Install NodeJS if it's not installed
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app go there and follow installation guide